# Find the domain of convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

> Find the domain of convergence of the series :
>
> $(1)$ $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{n!}\Big(\frac{1-z}{z}\Big)^n$$
>
> $(2)$ $$\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot5}z^2+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot5\cdot8}z^3 +\dots$$

I was reading Rudin and I know the following theorems

$\star $ For any sequence $\{c_n\}$ of positive numbers, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \sqrt[n]{c_n},$$ $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{c_n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}.$$

$\star $ [Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)

My Attempt :

$(1)$ If $c_n = \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{n!},$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n+1}{n+1}=2$

Hence the series converges if $|\frac{1-z}{z}|<1/2$ or if $|1-z|<|z|/2$ i.e., $|z|<3/2.$

$(2)$ Here similarly $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n+1}{3n-1}=2/3$

Hence series converges if $|z|<3/2.$

**Is this correct? $**

Comment: Well, for the first one we can use the ratio test:

$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left|\frac{\left(\frac{2\left(\text{n}+1\right)-1}{\left(\text{n}+1\right)!}\cdot\left(\frac{1-\text{z}}{\text{z}}\right)^{\text{n}+1}\right)}{\left(\frac{2\text{n}-1}{\text{n}!}\cdot\left(\frac{1-\text{z}}{\text{z}}\right)^\text{n}\right)}\right|=0<1\tag1$$

So it converges for all $\text{z}$ (but $\text{z}\ne0$).

Comment: @JanEerland  This is my confusion. So then why does the theorem claim that the series diverges for $|z|>3/2?$ What is it that I am not seeing?

Comment: (1) Your attempt (1) is wrong, as $\;\cfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\;$ is *not* what you write there, of course...though, surprisingly enough, the beginning bottom line result in this part is correct (read my answer below)...but not the last part ($\;|z|<\frac32\;$) . Something similar applies in (2).

Comment: @DonAntonio I see that in your answer $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2(n+1)^2}=\frac{(2n+1)}{(n+1)}$ ... isn't this what I got?

Comment: @BijeshK.S I honestly cannot see that I got that that you say...

Comment: @DonAntonio My point is : Since you mentioned that I got $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ wrong and then I see that in your answer you have also got the same, it confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first write

$$\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{n!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}{2^nn!n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}$$

and now apply the quotient test:

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1}\left((n+1)!\right)^2}\frac{(1-z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}\frac{z^n}{(1-z)^n}\right|=$$

$$=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2(n+1)^2}\left|\frac{1-z}z\right|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\left|\frac{1-z}z\right|\stackrel?<1\iff\left|\frac z{1-z}\right|>2$$

and putting $\;z=x+iy\;$ ,  the last inequality is the same as

$$x^2+y^2>4\left[(x-1)^2+y^2\right]\implies 3x^2-8x+4+3y^2<0\implies$$

$$3\left(x-\frac43\right)^2+3y^2<\frac43\iff \left|z-\frac43\right|<\frac23\;,\;\;z\neq1\; $$

which is almost an open disk of radius $\;\frac23\;$ around $\;\left(\frac43,0\right)\;$ on the complex plane.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x^2+y^2>4\left[(x-1)^2+y^2\right]$?

Comment: @BijeshK.S Completely true, thanks. I shall edit now...though the point is already clear, I think.